# How to use audioplayers package to keep playing song when the phone is closed?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a music app that works fine using audioplayer package, however when the phone's screen is closed, the music stop. How to keep playing the music when the phone is closed? Kindly help, thanks.

Comment: I would imagine that most use a foreground service on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are some flutter packages that play audio in the background and they are controlled on the lock screen.**

1. audio_service
2. audio_manager
3. flutter_playout

Comment: I will check them out, Thanks